# HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool format error

Tags: windows-7, bootable-media

I am using Windows 7, and trying to create a DOS bootable disk.

Ideally, I would like to be able to install a bootable version of Spinrite on it per these instructions - [Running Spinrite from a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/154045/running-spinrite-from-usb-drive)

But when I try to run the tool, it goes about 80% and then just says 'Failed to format the device'.

Thoughts ?

What other tools can I use to create a DOS bootable disk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a bootable DOS USB drive, download [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sf.net/) an excellent tool for making bootable USB drives for many different operating systems.  Once you've downloaded it, run it.  From the *Distribution* menu at the top, choose *FreeDOS*:

[image: UnNetbootin]

Select the drive you want to install it on at the bottom, and then click *OK*.  UNetbootin will then download [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/) and install it on your USB drive.

If you'd prefer to use a CD, the FreeDOS project also has a [LiveCD available for download](http://www.freedos.org/freedos/files/).

Comment: I actually got this working. What I did was formatted it as FAT instead - and did 'Quick Format'. That seems to have worked.

Comment: Btw, if you want to write this suggestion I will mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SpinRite is used from a bootable CD, you can use [XBoot](http://sites.google.com/site/shamurxboot/) to load from a selection of .iso images on the same USB flash drive.

I have a flash drive on my keyring, so I have a whole range of utility boot CDs, portable apps and scripts wherever I go.